# Flutter web located in a server folder

Tags: flutter, web, directory, location

I have recently upload a flutter website inside of a folder in my server.
But it's not working well. I have notice that main.dart.js needs to have the folder name in the url. But It is not working well... What more things I have to change for running the website without more problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the base path to you're index.html.

Example:

```
<base href="/FolderName/">
```

Comment: That's all. Thank you!!